# Pass C++ vector by reference and then do push_back()

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, stdvector

Consider this function to illustrate the case:

```
void appendAndPrint(std::vector<int> &v, int number)
{
    v.push_back(number);    // let there has been a reallocation
    std::cout << v.back();  // does the local reference v become invalid here?

    // is it safe, for example, to call here push_back() with v once again, like
    // v.push_back(number);
}
```

and then call it with some vector:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
appendAndPrint(vec, 5);
```

Is the reference passed into the function become invalid after the first vector reallocation?

EDIT:

This construction is used quite often, but where this kind of safety is referenced in the C++ Standard?

All what is mentioned is the lifetime of references/pointers/iterators to the container elements.

Comment: Your call to `push_back` will copy the value of the `int` so it is safe to call `push_back` again in your body

Comment: When people say reallocation "invalidates references", they mean it invalidates references to *elements*, not the container itself.

Comment: Pushing back an element in a vector can invalidate references to elements in the vector, but does not invalidate references to the vector itself.

Answer (score 3):

[Iterators and references to elements are invalidated,](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) but not container itself. It's normal code.

Comment: Is this mentioned in the Standard?

Comment: @trig-ger It must work, because nothing in the standard says it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The reference to the vector continues to be valid.

If you have any pointers or references (including iterators) to parts of the vector buffer, then these are invalidated by a reallocation, which might happen as a consequence of `push_back`.

You don't show any such pointers or references to the buffer, though.